# Equivalent Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

What's the equivalent eloquent query for:

```
SELECT `ip`
FROM items INNER JOIN ips ON items.client_id = ips.cient_id
WHERE serial_key = 12345
```

I have come up with this:

```
DB::table('items')
    ->join('ips', 'items.cient_id', '=', 'ips.client_id')
    ->where('items.serial_key', Request::get('serial_key'))
    ->select('ip')
    ->first();
```

It returns NULL.

How do I know that if it finds a record too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the call to `join()`:

```
join('ips', 'items.cient_id', '=', 'ips.client_id')
                   ^^^^^^^^
```